# How do you verify a tar archive that is already written?

Tags: tar

I know that you can use `-W` when creating an archive, but how do you verify and already-created archive? `tvWf` says it's not a valid tar archive?

```
$ mkdir tmp
$ echo asdkfjh > tmp/a
$ echo qweroiu > tmp/b
$ ls
tmp
$ tar cvf archive.tar tmp
tmp/
tmp/a
tmp/b
$ tar tvWf archive.tar
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Skipping to next header
tar: VERIFY FAILURE: 1 invalid header detected
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors
```

Same thing happens with both tar 1.15 (which is the system default on centos 5) and 1.26 (which is the newest version from gnu).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't use `W` with `t`.

```
mkdir tmp
echo bdb > tmp/a
echo bdb > tmp/b

tar cvf archive.tar tmp
tmp/
tmp/a
tmp/b

ls -l archive.tar
-rw-r--r-- 1 tony tony 10240 Jun 23 05:57 archive.tar

tar tvf archive.tar
drwxr-sr-x tony/tony         0 2011-06-23 05:57 tmp/
-rw-r--r-- tony/tony         4 2011-06-23 05:57 tmp/a
-rw-r--r-- tony/tony         4 2011-06-23 05:57 tmp/b

tar tvWf archive.tar
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Skipping to next header
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

I believe `t` alone is enough to test the archive.

Comment: `t` alone just lists the content of the archive. I want to verify that the files in the tar have the same contents as the originals (still on the file system), which I thought was what `W` should do (right?).

Comment: W does that only when *writing* the archive.  If you want to make sure the content is a byte for byte match you'll have to extract it somewhere and diff/sum the files.

Comment: Not for me: `tar tvWf t.tar` `tar: --verify cannot be used with -t`: `tar (GNU tar) 1.27.1`

Answer (score 16):

GNU `tar` has a `--compare` option. See the [Comparing Archive Members with the File System](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/compare.html) section of the documentation for details.

Comment: E.g. `tar -df /path/to/archive.tar.bz2` will show differences between files in the archive and the filesystem, resolving relative paths in the archive against the current working directory.

Comment: Yes. This is the answer. `tar -df folder.tar.bz2` does verify it. Add `-v` for verbose. On the other hand, `-W` or `--verify` do not work with compressed archives. It only works like `tar -cvWf folder.tar folder`. It verifies **right after** creating the archive, as it says in the man page.

Answer (score 3):

Joerg Schillings `star` sports a *diff* option, which is able to compare files in a tar archive with their original. You can state what should be recognized as difference.

```
0 1 newt pts/1 ~ 17> :> tmp/testfile
0 1 newt pts/1 ~ 19> star -cz tmp > tmp.tar
0 1 newt pts/1 ~ 19> echo bla > tmp/testfile
0 1 newt pts/1 ~ 20> star -z -diff diffopts=not,times < tmp.tar
diffopts=perm,symperm,type,nlink,uid,gid,uname,gname,size,data,rdev,hardlink,symlink,sympath,sparse,dir,acl,xattr,fflags
tmp/testfile: different size,data
star: 115 blocks + 0 bytes (total of 1177600 bytes = 1150.00k).
```

Note that it mentioned `testfile` as being of different size and data. If I hadn't excluded times (including access time!) it would have stated the access time as well, and also list all files whose times had changed just by looking at them.

Since the demise of BerliOS, `star` can be found at [sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/s-tar/).  It is highly portable, and compiles painlessly on most unixoid systems and unixoid look-alikes.

Comment: Recent sources are in the `schilytools` source package.

Answer (score 0):

The verification option is meant to be used during the creation, not after.
Also, compression is added afterwards.

```
%> tar -cvpWlf  test.tar sh.save
sh.save/
sh.save/test.tar
sh.save/Downloads/
sh.save/mount.sh
sh.save/Documents/
sh.save/skip_dirs_in_find.sh
Verify sh.save/
Verify sh.save/test.tar
Verify sh.save/Downloads/
Verify sh.save/mount.sh
Verify sh.save/Documents/
Verify sh.save/skip_dirs_in_find.sh
```

Although tar offers the "--compare" option.

`man tar`:

> -d, --diff, --compare
> Find differences between archive and file system.  The arguments
> are  optional  and  specify  archive members to compare.
> If not given, the current working directory is assumed.