# Verify an unpacked tar archive

Tags: tar

Is it possible to verify that a tar archive has been extracted correctly? Like a checksum of the extracted directory?

For some reason, certain files extracted by tar are erroneously created as empty files. It would be nice to detect this, like so:

```
$ tar xzf foo.tgz
$ <SOME_MAGIC_COMMAND>
  Error: foo/bar does not match file in archive
```

Comment: Does `tar tvzf foo.tgz` list the file sizes as non-zero?

Comment: See [How do you verify a tar archive that is already written](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15472/how-do-you-verify-a-tar-archive-that-is-already-written). The two answers other than the accepted one might answer your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `--compare` option of `tar`. From [man tar](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tar.1.html):

```
   tar {--diff|--compare} [--file ARCHIVE] [OPTIONS] [FILE...]

   -d, --diff, --compare
          Find differences between archive and file system.   The
          arguments  are  optional and specify archive members to
          compare.  If not given, the current  working  directory
          is assumed.
```

Example run with `a.txt`, `b.txt`, `c.txt` and `d.txt` in `archive.tgz`:

```
$ tar -df archive.tgz
tar: a.txt: Warning: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
c.txt: Mod time differs
c.txt: Size differs
d.txt: Mod time differs
```